# Unit Test with input parameter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nunit, moq

How to call method as a parameter into TestCase attribute NUnit?

Like we can write: [TestCase(1, 2, 3)]

How to call a function like below?:
[TestCase(SomeFunction(), 1, 2, 3)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try TestCaseSource attribute and use static method for your use case.

```
    public static IEnumerable<EditModel> Generator()
    {
        // You can also call methods here
        yield return new EditModel();
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(Generator))]
    public void DoSomething(EditModel model)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{model.commentText}");
    }
```

Comment: Why it should be an iterator block? I want to return only one model.
``
public static EditModel CreateEditModel()
{
 yield return new TestCaseData(new EditModel()
 {
  percent = 1.0M,
  count = 2345,
  commentText = "Comment Text",
  countryCode = "IND",
  countryEditID = 1,
  createdBy = "System",
  createdDate = DateTime.Now,
  criterionId = 1
 });
}
``

Comment: That's one way to call test methods with predefined data. You can return list of Models containing only one, necessary model.

Comment: Ok, that resolves my issue, can I do like below?

 [TestCaseSource(nameof(Generator), nameof(otherfunction1), nameof(otherfunction2))]

Comment: You can have comblex type returned from your method. You can have IEnumerable<object>(or object []) return type. See [documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/2.5/testCaseSource.html) paragraph 1.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the answer above, you could also try TestCaseSource attribute and implement a factory class for your test cases.

```
public class MyFactoryClass
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(MyMethod()).Returns(expectedTestResult);
            ....
        }
    }

    public EditModel MyMethod()
    {
        // Put method code here
        
        return editModel;
    }
}

public class MyTests
{
    [Test,TestCaseSource(typeof(MyFactoryClass),"TestCases")]
    public void DoSomething(EditModel model)
    {
        // Test code here.
    }

    ...
}
```